# touchesBegan and other touch events not getting detected in UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uinavigationcontroller, uitouch

In short, I want to detect a touch on the navigation controller titlebar, but having trouble actually catching any touches at all!

Everything is done without IB, if that makes a difference.

My app delegate's .m file contains:

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

There are a few other subviews added to this window in a way that overlays navigationController leaving only the navigation bar visible.

MyViewController is a subclass of UIViewController and its .m file contains:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
 for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
  NSLog(@"ended\n");
 } 

}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
  NSLog(@"began\n");
 } 
}
```

I also tried putting these functions directly into app delegate's .m file, but the console remains blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The overall setup of my app is a UINavigationController, UIScrollView and UIPageControl added to the window using [window addSubview:...] in the app delegate, in that order. The ScrollView then contains more views with the actual content of the app. The buttons of the UINavigationController work fine, but touches on the title do not get detected.

Comment: touchesEnded and began are UIView methods not UIViewController

Comment: Daniel is right... these will never get called in a UIViewController.

You need to make a UIView subclass with these methods, and then either assign that to be viewController.view or add it to the viewController's view as a subview (you would probably do either of these in the loadView method of the viewController.

Comment: I tried assigning a custom viewController.view but that does not seem to pick up touches on the navigation bar. If I get rid of all the other views and just leave navigationController and the view inside it, it only picks up touches on the inside of the view, but not on the bar.

Comment: @Daniel: touchesBegan/Ended are not UIView methods, they are [UIResponder](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIResponder) methods and a UIViewController is a UIResponder.

Comment: you should release thevariable viewController at the method dealloc .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, for lack of a better idea, I added another subview to my app, clear in color, placed programmatically over the navigation bar title and used a custom class for that view with relevant touch methods overridden. Works fine, but the I still wish there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: @Daniel No, it's perfect that way. Embedding the answer into the question by editing would make it much harder for us to find the solution if we had the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

The view controller is inserted into the responder chain between its managed view and the superview:

> Because view controllers are tightly bound to the views they manage, they are also part of the responder chain used to handle events. View controllers are themselves descendants of the UIResponder class and are inserted into the responder chain between the managed view and its superview. Thus, if the view managed by a view controller does not handle an event, it passes the event to its view controller, which then has the option of handling the event or forwarding it to the view’s superview.

(the [UIViewController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

Is it possible, that the managed view of your controller is eating all the events? What kind of view is it?

Comment: I am fairly new to this and not fluent with the whole view/controller relation, but in my case, the view inside MyViewController is actually blank. I just tried making a custom UIView subclass and overriding the touches methods from there, then using that subclass for the view of this controller, but that did not work either. 

The only purpose of this MyViewController is to provide a navigation bar with buttons and title.

Answer (score 4):

Had trouble with this, as my custom view was deeper in the view hierarchy. Instead, I climbed the responder chain until it finds a `UIViewController`;

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Pass to top of chain
    UIResponder *responder = self;
    while (responder.nextResponder != nil){
        responder = responder.nextResponder;
        if ([responder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
            // Got ViewController
            break;
        }
    }
    [responder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try adding the method userInteractionEnabled = YES to your UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

These methods should be put into the UIView subclass not the UIViewControllers...The UIView will receive the touches call backs, then you can make a protocol on the UIView and implement it on the UIViewController so the UIViewController will receive some call back when the touch events occur...Here is a link that talks about protocols and how to define them and implement them [Protocols Ref](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/articles/ocProtocols.html)